# Bad Route error caused by the order of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was having and bizarre error and I just want to understand why. I was getting a 'bad route' return from my css and Javascript files. As it turns all my paths were correct but the problem was caused by putting my

```
app.use(express.static('public')); after app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('Bad Route');
});
```

When I reversed the order it fixed the issue. Why does this cause a bad route error? Is it because of order of operations? My code for my app.js is below.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

//pages are inside routes folder

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/portfolio', routes.portfolio);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
res.send('Bad Route');
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware routes will fire in the order that they appear in your code. So if you have an `app.get()` that matches before the `app.static()`, then the `app.get()` will handle the request first. (It may choose to pass the request on to the next middleware.)

Comment: Okay, I figured that's what was happening. I'm not sure it states that in the docs though.

Comment: It's in http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html. It's possible it could be clearer. If so, consider forking https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com and submitting a PR with changes to the contents of https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com/blob/gh-pages/guide/using-middleware.md